# Rails - Adaptable field labels. Best way to use a models fields as labels for another models fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

New to Ruby on Rails and have come up against my first real difficulty in moving from a comfortable GUI IDE assistive functional language to RoR.

I need to have generic data as well as type specific data in a model. These types need to be unlimited in number and user definable.

e.g. a piece of equipment (kit) could be a vehicle, gas detector or any other type. If it's a vehicle then the type specific data might include registration number, registration renewal date, number of cylinders, etc. If it's a gas detector then it might be what types of gases it detects, amount of gas in cylinder, etc.

I have a model 'KitTypes' that records the labels for each type of specific Kit data that can be recorded for that type of Kit as per below.

```
class KitType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, 
    :info_label_1, :info_label_2, :info_label_3,  
    :date_label_1, :date_label_2, :date_label_3, 
    :num_label_1, :num_label_2, :num_label_3 
  has_many :kits
end
```

The equipment (kit) info is stored in the Kit model similar to the below. The Type specific field names are the info_n, date_n, num_n fields.

```
class Kit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :kit_type_id, :location_id, :code, :brand, :model, :serial, 
    :purchased, :purchase_price, :warranty_expiry, :decommission_date, :notes, 
    :info_1, :info_2, :info_3,
    :date_1, :date_2, :date_3,  
    :num_1, :num_2, :num_3
  belongs_to :kit_type
  belongs_to :location
end
```

The matching KitType record contains the display labels that should be displayed alongside the matching numbered Kit data.

Previously I would display the generic info in one view and the type specific info in a separate view. i.e. Users need to see all equipment in one grid but the type specific data only makes sense when looking at the same type records or an individual record. Also only those Kit fields with KitType label data would normally be visible, though at this stage that's not of primary importance.

I could separate the type specific data into another model but I don't see that gains me much and it still doesn't solve my adaptable label problem.

How do I do something similar in Rails (without being an expert yet) or am I approaching it all wrong?

Comment: You don't have to miss a good IDE if you program RoR. See question http://stackoverflow.com/q/91445/1065703

Answer (score 0):

Forgot all about this long newbie question of mine. So thought I would show what I did anyway.

In the end I add added code like this to my Kit model (kit.rb)

```
def info_lbl_1
  if !self.kit_type.blank?
    "N/A"
    if !self.kit_type.info_label_1.blank?
      self.kit_type.info_label_1
    end
  end
end
.....
```

and so on for each of the type labels. If there is no label then N/A (not applicable) is returned.

Then in the kit show view (show.html.erb) I added logic to display the labels as per below:

```
<% if @kit.info_lbl_1 !='N/A' %>
  <dt><strong><%= @kit.info_lbl_1 %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @kit.info_1 %></dd>
<% end %>
....
```

So the appropriate label for the customise type specific labels shows and the data is only displayed if there is a customised label that exists.

I'm sure I will re-factor it when I get more experienced so that I don't have to do code segments for each label via a helper or such but my initial attempts failed.

Comment: Better answer is http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms and even better is using postgresql hstore